# SSAS Does change in DSV effect old data browsing in cube?

Tags: ssas

I am new to SSAS Development , i need to know if i could change DSV in production cube by adding new columns into fact table  and in the same time  maintain to browse the partition data of previous years when the new column wasn't exist in cube structure.

I tried to add new column in underling fact Then i refreshed the DSV then i deploy the cube with do not process then process the last partition full process but the cube browse stop due the old partition doesn't been processed. could any one tell what should i do.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it'll help you but I would say you need to process all the partitions (including old partitions) with a "Full process" or you can process each partitions starting with the oldest.

An example : your partitions are based on dates and you want to see the "Total" sum() of your new measure. You'll need to know the sum() of your new measure realated on each old date in order to get this "Total" sum().

This is just an idea, maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Thank you Nick but my new column measure is presented as new service in current year i want to reflect it for the current partition year without effecting old data but any change in the data sources ends me with full process to old data partitions